# Netty DelimiterBasedFrameDecoder/multiline

Tags: java, tcp, netty

I have a hopefully not too unique problem.  I am trying to setup a syslog handler in Netty, but I have a syslog source that isn't providing well formed single line syslog messages.

In short, the syslog format uses the newline as a delimiter, and a message starts with a less than character '<'.

I've got a simple example below of the TCP stream being generated.  I'm trying to figure out how to parse each line or line set as one Frame.

```
<128>2014-02-03T12:00:00 localhost program[pid]: message
<128>2014-02-03T12:00:00 localhost program[pid]: message
<128>2014-02-03T12:00:00 localhost program[pid]: exception occurred
    at package.Class.function:line
    at package.Class.function:line
    at package.Class.function:line
    at package.Class.function:line
<128>2014-02-03T12:00:00 localhost program[pid]: message
```

One thought was to use/modify [DelimiterBasedFrameDecoder](http://netty.io/4.0/api/io/netty/handler/codec/DelimiterBasedFrameDecoder.html) to look for `\n<`, but leave the < on the buffer, but also, just `\n` if there is no more data queued.

Another thought was to consume each line as a separate frame, and then merge them in another handler, but I can't find an example that does this.  I also don't know if Netty will maintain sequence of frames for reassembly with a large worker pool.

Suggestions?

Comment: Mike Heath wrote a syslog codec for Netty already. Doesn't it solve your problem already? https://github.com/mheath/syslog-netty-codec

Comment: His doesn't do any lookahead, and it in a tcp stream it can grab the next line if it's already available.